# Extracting numeric range "values" from a Ruby Hashtable or JSon object

Tags: ruby, hashtable, range, numeric

I am quite new to Ruby (1.8.7), and would like to be able to extract values from a Hashtable which are within a specific numeric range (without having to iterate through the values).

If I have Hashtable with:

```
my_hash = {
  55 => {:value=>61, :rating=>147},
  89 => {:value=>72, :rating=>200},
  78 => {:value=>64, :rating=>300}
}
```

How would I parse the Hashtable so the rating=>300 was returned (if a range of 250..350) was specified?  Alternatively I will sort the Hashtable on the rating value and iterate checking each value individually.

Thanks,

Miles.

Answer (score 1):

To return my_hash entries within a range of ratings:

```
my_hash.select { |k,v| (250..350).include?(v[:rating]) }
```